# Magento 1.9.x ORM query to get past successful orders with specific billing street, city, state and zip

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, orm

I need an ORM query to get all past successful orders with a specific billing street address, city, state and zip code? ie:

```
$street = '999 west rd';
$city = 'my town';
$state = 'New York';
$zip = '90001';

//write ORM query to get all past
//successful orders with all those exact values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the address components are not indexed in the DB, so the following query will scan all the success orders in the address table.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.state', array('in'=>array('complete', 'processing'))) // successful orders, is 'closed' state success?
    ->addFieldToFilter('a.street', $street)
    ->addFieldToFilter('a.city', $city)
    ->addFieldToFilter('a.region', $state)
    ->addFieldToFilter('a.postcode', $zip)
    ->addFieldToFilter('a.address_type', 'billing'); // another type is 'shipping'
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('a' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_address')),
    'a.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',
    array()
);
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $result[$item->getId] = $item->getData();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: thx. why both `complete` and `processing`?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you considered as *successful* orders. You can filter for whatever states or statuses as required.